# Package project: Linux vs LinuxArm64

Tags: game-development, unreal-engine5

What is the difference between Linux vs LinuxArm64? Linux - is 32 bit?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux - 32 and 64 bit - Laptops/Computers/Servers running on Intel, AMD x86_64 CPU's with Linux OS

Linux ARM architecture 64 bit - Devices running on ARM CPU's with 64 bit Linux such as Raspberry PI or some Amazon VM's